# jQuery closest() not grabbing element

Tags: jquery

Ok the .closest() function is not grabbing the element correctly or AT ALL so the class is not being added to the div. What's wrong here?

HTML:

```
<div class="half control-group">
        <div class="form-status"></div>
        <?php
        echo form_label('Username', 'username');
        echo form_input(array('name' => 'username', 'maxlength' => 25, 'value' => set_value('username') ));
        ?>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
success: function(label) {
    $(label).text('');
    $(label).closest('div[class="form-status"]').addClass('success');
    //label.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
}
```

It's making the text go to blank correctly, but it's not changing the closest form-status div class... i even tried closest('.form-status') and it still won't grab it.
I'm using the validate jQuery plugin.
When you start typing it adds this HTML underneath the input bars:

```
<label for=​"name" generated=​"true" class=​"error valid" style>​​</label>​
```

FOR ANYONE LOOKING FOR THE CORRECT ANSWER, THIS WORKED:

```
label.closest('.control-group').find('div.form-status').addClass('success');
```

Answer (score 3):

[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) only goes up the dom tree, it doesn't select siblings.

You need

```
$(label).prev('div.form-status').addClass('success');
```

or

```
$('.half.control-group label').prev('div.form-status').addClass('success');
```

depending of if the label var you get is a jQuery selector or not.

Note that as I commented before, there is a direct selector for classes both in jQuery and CSS so you should prefer `'div.form-status'` over `'div[class="form-status"]'`.

Comment: You should remove your comment under the answer. Also, it'd be good to explain that `div[class="form-status"]` is error prone because it will fail as soon as you add a new class to that div

Comment: @JuanMendes I removed my comment but I think yours is clear enough regarding the problem with more than one class ;)

Comment: This: $(label).prev('div.form-status').addClass('success'); does still not work.. it's not adding that class onto the DIV.. And Chrome Debugger isn't throwing any error messages like it usually does if jQuery is messing up.

Comment: Do the line before this one work ? Is your label already added to the page ? What's in the label string ?

Comment: The line before does work. And so did this one: label.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').addClass('success'); which was the default it came with, but i am trying to style it differently. The label is already added to the page. The string gets turned to '' since I didn't want OK! being shown which was the default it came with.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you try to do exactly. Does this work : `$('label').prev('div.form-status').addClass('success');` ?

Comment: Yes that does work.. I don't know why you had to have the quotes, but it works now. Update your answer. It's marking BOTH div.form-status's that I have on the page with it, but I'll just go back to closest.

Comment: WAIT why is it applying to ALLLLLL Div's that have the form-status class?... I only want it applying to the closest one.. O_O

Comment: Use this : $('.half.control-group label') to target only the label inside the form which has classes half and control-group.

Comment: All of my form elements are wrapped in the half and control-group class... so.... it's still doing it to all of them.

Comment: This works: label.closest('.control-group').find('div.form-status').addClass('success');

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this one and working quite well:

```
$('label').text(''); 
$('label').prev('div[class="form-status"]').addClass('success');
// ---------^---------use this if you want to add class to just previous div at 
//--------------------same level
```

use this if you want to add class to all divs at same level

```
$('label').siblings('div[class="form-status"]').addClass('success');
```

Comment: It's not working for me... it doesn't even change ANY of the DIV's that have form-status as the class...

Answer (score 0):

Half the problem has been explained, you should use `$.prev()` because `$.closest()` doesn't look at siblings.

However, the second part of the problem lies here

```
// What type is label? Is it a string indicating what's in the 
// for="name"? Is it a jQuery object? a DOM object
success: function(label) {
    $(label).text('');
    $(label).closest('div[class="form-status"]').addClass('success');
    //label.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
}
```

If it's being passed a jQuery or HTMLElement object, the following would work http://jsfiddle.net/Rdpu7/1/

```
success: function(label) {
    $(label).prev('div.form-status').addClass('success');
    $(label).text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').addClass('success');        
}
```

If it's being passed the `name` that was passed into `form_label`, you can use the following http://jsfiddle.net/Rdpu7/3/

```
success: function(label) {
    var label = $("label[for='"+label+"']");
    label.prev('div.form-status').addClass('success');
    label.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').addClass('success');  
}
```

If it's something else, you should improve your documentation, I particularly can't stand function where the parameters aren't documented, and I'm sure it's the reason for your confusion.

With regards to why the following line worked

```
$('label').prev('div.form-status').addClass('success')
```

That will do all the labels on your page, which is not likely what you want. It only works for the example with a single label. Your main problem is that you don't know what type of object `label` is in your success function